# bootstrap-maxlength always on top

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Using bootstrap-maxlength plugin : https://github.com/mimo84/bootstrap-maxlength

It works pretty well, but when a bootstrap modal pops in, this plugin's remaining character label is still being shown over the modal.

Thank you in advance.

---Edit---

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function){
   //textareaID is the element where i want to wrap charactercounter
   $('#textareaID').maxlength({
      showOnReady: false,
      alwaysShow: true,
      threshold: 10,
      warningClass: 'label label-success',
      limitReachedClass: 'label label-important label-danger',
      separator: ' / ',
      preText: '',
      postText: '',
      showMaxLength: true,
      placement: 'top',
      message: 'Remaining chars: %charsRemaining%',
      showCharsTyped: true,
      validate: true,
      utf8: false,
      appendToParent: true,
      twoCharLinebreak: true,
      customMaxAttribute: null,
      allowOverMax: false
   });
}
```

**And also, the plugin generates its html as like :**

```
<span class="bootstrap-maxlength label label-success" style="display: block; position: absolute; white-space: nowrap; z-index: 1099; top: -22px; left: 395.453px;">Remaining chars: 989</span>
```

Comment: The screenshot does nothing to help me help you; maybe replace the screenshot with code that demonstrates the problem so I may reproduce it.

Comment: @ThisClark i added my code into the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this element appears over the `modal` is because of its `z-index` attribute. In the `Bootstrap` source code, there is a list of `z-index` attributes defined for common elements:

```
@zindex-navbar:                 1000;
@zindex-dropdown:               1000;
@zindex-popover:                1060;
@zindex-tooltip:                1070;
@zindex-navbar-fixed:           1030;
@zindex-modal-background:       1049; /* Blurry Modal back-drop */
@zindex-modal:                  1050; /* Actual Modal */
```

In the source code for `maxlength.js`, we can see this code:

```
if (!maxLengthIndicator) {
  maxLengthIndicator = $('<span class="bootstrap-maxlength"></span>').css({
    display: 'none',
    position: 'absolute',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    zIndex: 1099 // Notice here, z-index is higher than the Bootstrap modal
  }).html(maxlengthContent);
}
```

As you can see, the `z-index` 1099 is larger than the `modal`'s 1049 and 1050. If you don't want this to appear above the `modal`, you can alter `bootstrap-maxlength.js` and change the `z-index` of this generated element, or change it with jQuery after your call `.maxlength({ })` for the first time:

```
$('.bootstrap-maxlength').css({ z-index: 1040 });
```

Lastly, the `github` page says:

> The indicator badge shows up on focusing on the element, and disappears when the focus is lost.

Which, to me, means your issue shouldn't even be an issue, as the `modal` appearing should trigger a de-focus of your `<textarea>`, but I don't have any way to test that currently. That being said, you could trigger a `blur()` on `$("#textareaID")` when your modal opens, which should hide the maxlength `<span>` generated by the plug-in:

```
$("#exampleModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
  $("#textareaID").blur();
});
```

Hopefully this provides some insight for you.

Comment: zindex is the answer, i found it, but thanks anyway !

Comment: I changed zIndex to 1000 which is quite fine for me. Thank you very much for the explanation though.

Comment: No worries, just be aware of the caveats of changing the z-index. Glad you got it working though :P